# How to update a Cell Value in DataGridView c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a DataGridView, i want to change value of a cell after getting data from DB

I'm using this following code:

```
var query = (from p in dbc.Table
                     select new
                     {
                         p.name,
                         p.balance,
                     }
                        ).ToList();

        datagridview.DataSource = query;

        decimal CellValue;

        CellValue = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvRechercheTier.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value) * (-1);

        dgvRechercheTier.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = CellValue;
```

But this not working

Comment: Your `DataSource` is attached, then you need to deal with the data source to add/remove/edit items. Yet better, use [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Once you'e gotten the new data from the DB why not just refresh the whole DGV?